# Convergence of series and finding range of other variable.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a series
$$ \left(\,{\sum_ {k\ge 1} \, {\mid x_k^s \mid}^p \,}\right)^{1 \over p} < \infty $$
where $1 \le p < \infty $, and I want to find the range of values of s in $\mathbb R$ such that $x_k = k$.
I solve as  below.
$$ \left(\,{\sum_ {k\ge 1} \, {\mid x_k^s \mid}^p \,}\right)^{1 \over p} < \infty $$
$$ \implies {\sum_ {k\ge 1} \, {\mid x_k^s \mid}^p \,} < \infty $$
$$ \implies {\sum_ {k\ge 1} \, {x_k^{sp} } \,} < \infty $$
$$ \implies a_n =x_n ^{sp} $$
Using Ratio test
$$  L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \left|  {a_{n+1} \over a_n} \right| $$
$$  L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \left|  {x_{n+1}^{sp} \over x_n^{sp}} \right| $$
$$  L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \left|  {(n+1)^{sp} \over n^{sp}} \right|$$
Does the solution correct till this point and how to solve it further to get value of $s \in \mathbb R$

Comment: That limit is $1$ for all $p,s$ so the ratio test is inconclusive for all $s.$

Comment: If you let $r=ps$ what you are really asking is when is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^r$$ convergent. Clearly, you need at minimum $r<0,$ because otherwise $n^r$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I got the point but I think r<-1 since $$ \sum_{n\ge 1} {1 \over n} $$ is divergent.

Comment: I didn’t say $r<0$ was sufficient, only that it was necessary.

Comment: Sure @ThomasAndrews check the answer and give your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f(x)$ a decreasing positive function on $[1,\infty)$ we have that:

$$f(k) \geq \int_k^{k+1} f(x)\,dx \geq f(k+1)$$
Summing, we get:
$$\int_1^{n+1} f(x)\,dx\leq \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)\leq f(1)+\int_1^n f(x)\,dx$$

Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ on both sides, we see that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)$ converges if and only if $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ converges.

Then, if $r<0$ take $f(x)=x^r,$and find out when $$\int_1^\infty x^r\,dx$$
converges.

Answer (score 0):

$${\sum_ {k\ge 1} \, {x_k^{sp} } \,} < \infty $$
Let r=sp
$${\sum_ {k\ge 1} \, {x_k^{r} } \,} < \infty \iff  r< -1$$
$$ sp < -1$$
$$ s< {-1  \over p}$$